# HELP NEEDED, I can NOT get order endpoints to work in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using zapier to bring an order from one website to Magento 2 with a webhook. I can not find the endpoint for ordering. I believe this is the only information I need to finish this. I found a document with the needed information from Shopify but cant find a match for Magento 2, Here is the Shopify code:

```
{  
 "order": { 
   "line_items":[ 
      { 
         "variant_id": xxxxxxxx,
         "quantity": 1, 
         "fulfillment_status": "null" 
      } 
    ], 

 "customer": { 
   "first_name": "[Advocate's First Name]",
   "last_name": "[Advocate's Last Name]", 
   "email": "[Advocate's Email]"
  }, 

"financial_status": "pending", 

"shipping_address": { 
   "first_name": “[Advocate’s First Name]", 
    "last_name": “[Advocate’s Last Name]", 
    "address1": “[Advocate’s Address]", 
    "address2": “[Advocate’s Redemption ID]", 
    "city": “[Advocate’s City]", 
    "province": “[Advocate’s Province/State]", 
    "country": “[Advocate’s Country]", 
    "zip": “[Advocate’s ZIP]" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is official document you can find all endpoints https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html